# GetSelection in Google Spreadsheet (selected text/row/colums)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Im looking for something to get what is selected in a spreadsheet. I would like the users to select a couple of rows. And get the selected data in the rows in a variable.

I know this is possible with DocumentApp. But can it be done with Spreadsheet, i haven't found anything good.

**Docs:**

```
 var selection = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection();
```

**Spreadsheet:**

```
var selection = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().
```

Can't do the `.getSelection();` here, what could i do instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet Name");
//For range
var activerange = sheet.getActiveRange().getValues();
//for cell
var activecell = sheet.getActiveCell().getValue();
```

You can use `getActiveRange` or `getActiveCell` to get data from active range.